# Tox set default values for missing environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, tox

I'd like to set default values to environment variables that are missing within [tox](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) but only if they're missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works via the [env substitution](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html?highlight=substitution#environment-variable-substitutions-with-default-values). An example for either using `TOX_WORKDIR` or the default:

tox.ini

```
[tox]
envlist = py
skipsdist = true

[testenv]
setenv = TOX_WORKDIR = {env:TOX_WORKDIR:.tox}
commands = python ./envecho.py
```

envecho.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

print(os.getenv("TOX_WORKDIR"))
```

output without env set:

```
$ tox

py create: /home/oliver/Dropbox/projects/tox/lab/mini/.tox/py
py installed: appdirs==1.4.3,packaging==16.8,pyparsing==2.2.0,six==1.10.0
py runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='2704413679'
py runtests: commands[0] | python ./envecho.py
.tox
______________________________ summary ______________________________
  py: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

output with env set:

```
$ TOX_WORKDIR=/tmp/ tox

py installed: appdirs==1.4.3,packaging==16.8,pyparsing==2.2.0,six==1.10.0
py runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='30398946'
py runtests: commands[0] | python ./envecho.py
/tmp/
______________________________ summary ______________________________
  py: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```